# I want to create a tkinter frame with 100% width

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

The following code is to use GUI in python. So I tried to make header with 100% width size current window using frames. But I'm not getting result as I want.

```
# frames
header_frame=Frame(window, bg='#0c446e', width='100', height='10',pady=10, padx=10)
header_frame.pack()
# header text
loginheader=Label(header_frame, text=h1, fg='#fdde0e', bg='#0c446e',justify='center', anchor='center', font='Arial 16 bold',)
loginheader.pack()
```

Comment: Use `header_frame .propagate(0)` so the children widget won't take over the size of parent widget.

Comment: @saad: the use of `propagate(0)` is almost never the right solution. It will make a GUI that isn't reponsive to changes in resolution or font changes.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the frame to be 100% the width of its window, use the `side` and `fill` options of pack:

```
header_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```